# How do I cook beans without having too many that are split?

Tags: beans

Whenever I have cooked beans from raw (dried), many of the beans split. But if I buy canned beans, there are fewer split beans. How are the canned beans cooked so that there are fewer split beans?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beans split because the seed coat isn't soft enough when the interior of the bean rehydrates.

Two factors that can help ease this problem:

1. soak your beans to make sure the seed coat is well rehydrated when the bean interior cooks.
2. This is the big one- heavily salt your soaking water. The salt ions will replace calcium in the bean skins and soften them. You will have magically whole beans.

Refer to [the Food Lab article](http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/01/how-to-make-the-best-chili-ever-recipe-super-bowl.html) on chili which contains this image:
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I have been seeing with my beans. Thanks!